# Is there a way to use 'python3.9 -m pip download' for dowloading packages from a file with multiple constrain?

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

I'm trying to use pip to download all the packages listed in a file and put them inside a directory. For this job, I need to download the latest version AND a specific version of that package (so I need to have the tar of the latest version of RANDOM-PACKAGE and the version 2.1.1 of RANDOM-PACKAGE inside this directory)

The command that I use is:
`python3 -m pip download -r $FILE_TO_READ --dest $PACKAGES_DIR`
This command works for python 3.6 (it gets all the packages without problems, last version AND specific version) but it doesn't work for Python 3.7 or more (I'm using the 3.9 version)
The specific error that I got with Python3.9 is:

> ERROR: Double requirement given: contexter==0.1.4 (from -r /home/lab/working_environment/packages_to_update.txt (line 15)) (already in contexter (from -r /home/lab/working_environment/packages_to_update.txt (line 14)), name='contexter')

The file is a *.txt* file and its structured like this:

```
astpretty
bleach
blivet
bottle
build
certifi
cffi
chardet
charset-normalizer
colorama
commentjson
conan
configobj
contexter
contexter==0.1.4
cryptography
dasbus
dbus-python
decorator
```

How can I resolve this error without creating a separated file for the constraints, or using a parser for modify the file ?

Comment: See how the file specifies `contexter` and also `contexter==0.1.4`? Did you try removing one of those? What version of `contexter` do you want to be installed (or does it matter), and why?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel This is what the OP exactly wants: to download **both** `contexter` (the latest version) and `contexter==0.1.4`.

Comment: You mention in your question the Python versions, but I think you should also mention the pip versions. -- Also, I think you should run two `pip download` commands, one to get the unconstrained versions and one to get the constrained versions, or whatever other combination that works for you.

Comment: I can't understand the goal of downloading both. How should the code know which one to use, for example? What problem is solved by having both available?

Comment: I need both available because I'm running a pip server inside a private network, the developers that need to download this packages do not have access to the outside network and directly download them from my local server.
Some of them need the latest version of a package, others need a specific version. This file is a collection of package needed by all the developer and it run on a pipeline, so the process it automatic and start each time this file is modified by some of the developer.
For now I'm uploading them manually, but I need to automated it. This is why i need them both.

Comment: My specific versions are : 
- Python: 3.9.13
- pip: 20.2.4

Answer (score 0):

The error shows that there is duplication in the **contexter** package, remove it and see if the issue has been resolved.

**UPDATE:**
try to use --no-deps flag in your script and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: This is what the OP exactly wants: to download **both** `contexter` (the latest version) and `contexter==0.1.4`.

Comment: yeah you're right I'm sorry I'll update the answer

Comment: Saw the update, but it didn't work. Still have the problem : /
Maybe its not possible with python 3.9 but I don't know why with 3.6 yes